# jQuery add active class to parent on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image]
(All child is active as shown in the picture)
I want to add class="active" to parent when its child is clicked. I manage to add class "active" to parent but all the child is added class= "active" too. What i want is only the chosen child and its parent is "active".

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var filename=pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

var currentLink=$('a[href="' + filename + '"]'); //Selects the proper a tag
currentLink.parents('.doctormenu').find('li a').removeClass('active'); 
currentLink.parentsUntil('.doctormenu', 'li').addClass('active'); 
//currentLink.parent().addClass("active");
//alert(filename);
})
```

Html:

```
<ul class="doctormenu">
  <li><a href="index.html" class="active">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="testabout.php">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="testdisease.php">Disease</a></li>
  <li><a href="login.html">Search</a></li>




  <li><a href="#" >
  Services</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="asdqq.html">Self Diagnosis</a></li>
  <li><a href="testservice.php">Online Consultation</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Clinic Appointment</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fmdrLx1/) with a proper demo**

The important code would be this:

```
// you can change this on.hashchange for the on.documentready
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
  // select a reference, in your case can be the pathname or whatever
  var ref = location.hash
  // find the matching element
  var $el = $('a[href="' + ref + '"]')
  // and it's closest parent (avoid select other 
  // parents and it's less risky than .parent)
  var $menu = $el.closest('.doctormenu')

  // remove previous active, if there's any 
  // (may you don't need this if the page is reloading)
  $('.doctormenu')
    .removeClass('active')
    .find('a')
    .removeClass('active')

  // execute the needed operations, adding class in this example
  $el.addClass('active')
  $menu.addClass('active')
});
```

Comment: I thought  i don't need to add .click() as the link is redirect to another page?

Comment: So you want to add `.active` to the `<a>` which `href` match something in the url?

Comment: I added picture in the question. My problem is there. All child is "active". I want only the specific child and its parent "active"

Comment: Now child problem solved. But parent is not "active".

Comment: As you can see in my jsfiddle the classes toggling is working. So I guess that the problem is the selector. Check that the `$menu` variable is the parent that you're expecting. And also, as a suggestion, if you changed the original content please update the question so we can track the changes also ;)

Comment: Your jsfiddle don't have child menu. I think $menu.addClass('active') is not working

Comment: Mmmm, yeah, that's what I told you: the selector. I don't know what do you mean with "child menu". You placed a two-level nested HTML and that's what's on the fiddle.

Comment: i mean like this <ul><li><a>menu2</a><ul><li><a>menu 2.1</a></li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: Bro i found my mistake. i have wrong setting in css. My code is correct from the beginning. Thanks for help

Comment: May you can reply to yourself and mark it as resolved so others we'll be less prone to make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.doctormenu li a').each(function(){
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code only add "active" to selected one.How to add "active" to parent if submenu is selected?